# Deloy on AKS Elastic stack

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, azure-aks, .net-6.0, serilog

I tried to deploy on Azure Kubernetes Elastic stack following this example [ELASTIC.IO](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-run-elastic-cloud-on-kubernetes-from-azure-kubernetes-service).I want to get logs from mine.Net6 WebApi.For logger I use Serilog. I was made docker-compose to run the elastic stack on the local docker container to test on the development environment and everything works fine. The problem comes with AKS deployment, I see that on Kubernetes all servers are working. I have access to elastic port 9200 with curl but in production returns me empty reply from server
,  and to the Kibana dashboard, but for some reason when I start the app from my PC with production settings to point elastic deployed on AKS I can't create any index or see any changed data.

```
    {
  "ApplicationName": "identity-service",
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimiumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Ovveride": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ElasticConfiguration": {
    "URI": "https://elasic-cloud-ip:9200"
  }
}
```

And this is the configuration that works in the development environment.

```
var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
        {
           Console.Out.WriteLine($"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name.ToLower()}-{env.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}");
            configuration.Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(
                new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(context.Configuration["ElasticConfiguration:URI"]))
                {
                    IndexFormat = $"{context.Configuration["ApplicationName"].ToLower()}-{env.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}",
                    AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                    NumberOfShards = 1,
                    NumberOfReplicas = 2
                })
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", context?.HostingEnvironment?.EnvironmentName?.ToLowerInvariant())
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
        });
```

Comment: `https://elasic-cloud-ip:9200` careful with that, there's malicious bots out there actively scanning for open Elasticsearch servers.